# Angular 13 dynamic locale change

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

To localize my Angular 13 application I followed the official guide: https://angular.io/guide/i18n-example, created *.xlf files with translations, everything seems to work fine so far.

Now, I wonder if it's possible to dynamically change the current display language (current locale and translations) without recompiling and reloading the Angular application, **keeping the same Url address**. For example, I'd like to have a Combobox in the component and when the user selects a different language, dynamically change the UI display language for the entire site. Is this possible using the default i18n Angular 13 functionality? Should I use [ngx-translate](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate) instead of the default one? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

possible solutions with **i18n** (u will need reload page 100% at this time angualr i18n can't update displayed data in runtime):

1. use some subdomain like en.domain.com & fr.domain.com and when language changed navigate user
2. use some prefix (like in first) domain.com/en OR domain.com/fr
3. using localStorage (or other storage) for storing selected language

with using **ngx-translate** u can saw actually language when it changed (runtime updated)